# Can RHEL6 based kernel be upgraded with RHEL7 kernel version

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

To fix an issue with the kernel I need to upgrade it from 2.6.32.xxx.el6 to a 3.10.0.xxx.el7 but I am little skeptical because the version of Operating system is 6.10. Is it possible to upgrade new kernel of a recent/later OS version?

Could someone brief the challenges in doing so?

Answer (score 1):

Version string of "el7" means RHEL 7 based. You would need to upgrade the OS to EL 7 to use such a kernel.

That upgrade to EL 7 or 8 is a good idea anyway. There is limited time left in the maintenance support phase for EL 6, after which no updates.

Third party repos exist with newer kernel versions, or of course you could compile your own. This would not be a 3.10 el7 build. It does not add any more time to EL 6's end of life clock.  However, it would be a newer kernel.